# Android handling simultaneous permissions from different sources

Tags: android, android-permissions

I am trying to request multiple permissions at the same time, coming from multiple sources. My problem is that only one permission is being requested.

Here's an example :

We have 2 fragments which are loaded at the same time on MainActivity such as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.myapplication.MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <fragment android:name="com.example.myapplication.fragments.FragmentOne"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_one"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <fragment android:name="com.example.myapplication.fragments.FragmentTwo"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_two"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

We have FragmentOne that requests READ_CALL_LOG such as

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    Log.d(TAG, "onStart: ");
    requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CALL_LOG}, 1);
}
```

We also have FragmentTwo that requests READ_CONTACTS such as

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    Log.d(TAG, "onStart: ");
    requestPermissions(new String[] { Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS }, 2);
}
```

What this means is that as soon as the application launches, the 2 fragments are created, then started. When that happens, both fragments request a permission at the same time. My problem is that only the first permission is ever prompted to the user.

Now to figure out my problem, I added some logs in onRequestPermissionsResult of each fragments such as

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    Log.d(TAG, "onRequestPermissionsResult: requestCode=" + requestCode + " permissions=" + permissions
            + " permissions.length=" + permissions.length + " grantResults.length=" + grantResults.length);
    for (String permission : permissions) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onRequestPermissionsResult: permission=" + permission);
    }
}
```

Following that I found my problem, but am left with no solution.
When I looked at the logs, as soon as I launch the app, I get these logs

```
2017-05-02 13:22:40:0356    + 677   05-02 13:22:38.650 27003 27003 D FragmentOne: onStart:
2017-05-02 13:22:40:0357    + 699   05-02 13:22:38.661 27003 27003 D FragmentTwo: onStart:
2017-05-02 13:22:40:0357    + 702   05-02 13:22:38.661 27003 27003 D FragmentTwo: onRequestPermissionsResult: requestCode=2 permissions=[Ljava.lang.String;@afbcb45 permissions.length=0 grantResults.length=0
```

At the same moment, the dialog requesting READ_CALL_LOG is displayed.
The problem here seems to be that it goes into onRequestPermissionsResult too early.

As soon as I accept the READ_CALL_LOG permission from the dialog, I get 2 new logs

```
2017-05-02 13:27:42:0017    + 2803  05-02 13:27:40.358 27003 27003 D FragmentOne: onRequestPermissionsResult: requestCode=1 permissions=[Ljava.lang.String;@5028ba8 permissions.length=1 grantResults.length=1
2017-05-02 13:27:42:0017    + 2804  05-02 13:27:40.358 27003 27003 D FragmentOne: onRequestPermissionsResult: permission=android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG
```

At that point, the second permission dialog (for READ_CONTACTS) that I was expecting is NOT displayed. No further logs are generated.

Now, I know that I could get all the permissions from the different fragments and prompt them all at the same time by passing the relevant String array. But that is not what I am trying to accomplish here. I am trying to have multiple components handle their own permissions.

Am I missing something? Am I doing something wrong?

For reference, I will put here the full code of MainActivity and of FragmentOne. FragmentTwo pretty much the same thing (Only the TAG and the permission change).

MainActivity :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

FragmentOne :

```
public class FragmentOne extends Fragment {

    private static final String TAG = "FragmentOne";

    public FragmentOne() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment_one, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Log.d(TAG, "onStart: ");
        requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CALL_LOG}, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        Log.d(TAG, "onRequestPermissionsResult: requestCode=" + requestCode + " permissions=" + permissions
                + " permissions.length=" + permissions.length + " grantResults.length=" + grantResults.length);
        for (String permission : permissions) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onRequestPermissionsResult: permission=" + permission);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the permission requests in the activity instead of the fragment and request both at the same time. 
What seems to be the problem is that when you request the second permission the first dialog is closed so it is treated as denied.

Comment: That's what I ended up doing in the end. But it does not solve the actual problem. Which is permissions do not seem to be handled correctly in fragments. Or at least, they are, but only if there is a single fragment requiring permissions running at a single time. I find it strange that Fragment offers the requestPermissions method, if it does not handle correctly multiple fragments.